# Releasing with ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

Basic question here. I started using ARC and am not sure if I should release objects in situations where another object takes ownership.

e.g. `[self.view addSubview:someViewController.view];`

Should this view be released or can I just leave it as is?

Same goes for an array, when adding objects to an array, should I release them afterwards because the array has the object ownership or can I just leave it?

Comment: Don't use the [tag:arc] for [tag:automatic-ref-counting] questions, as it is scheduled to be disambiguated. For more details, look here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137914/disambiguate-the-arc-tag

Comment: You can't even call `release` with ARC enabled, it will give you a compiler error.

Comment: @omz technically, that isn't true. You can do that with `CFRelease`/`CFRetain` or `objc_msgSend`, or even casting to a `__unsafe_unretained` pointer. But it should be noted that it is NEVER in your best interests to do that.

Comment: I will be using Core-Audio with this application. Can I still use CFRelease as usual even if the project is ARC based? I could turn ARC of for those source files right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this sitiuation `[self.view addSubview:someViewController.view];`, if someViewController is a strong property then after using it, you should call `self.someViewController = nil`

For an array you dont call release on the objects, but if the array is a strong property then you will need to set it to nil when you are done with it

Comment: Arent all objects strong be default? So I should just set all objects to nil when done with them. e.g. in the viewDidUnload method?

Comment: Yes if you didnt specify them as weak, then you will have to set them to nil when u are done with them

Comment: My mind is blown when I think that a multiverse could be in a cluster, that could even be in a lower dimension of a larger structure and so on, all stemming from a source recursively. Fragments in time.

Comment: i like that, and i like his more practical works too, he truly is a great guy,

Comment: The word genius is thrown around a lot. He truly is a genius.

Answer (score 1):

With ARC you *may not* release anything. The compiler will figure out when and where to release a given object -- you're not allowed to do it yourself.

If you're *not* using ARC, then the answer would be: Release an object *if* you've retained (or copied, alloc'ed, or created using new) it, *and* you're done with the reference. So, if you create an object using `alloc`, add it to an array, and subsequently no longer need to keep track of that object yourself, then yes, you should release it. Arrays and other collections will retain objects that they contain. But again, that's only if you're *not* using ARC; if you *are* using it, then you don't need to worry about releasing anything.

Answer (score 0):

No releasing and retaining anymore in ARC, just leave it as it is.